# Table doesn't fit

Tags: tables

I want to the table to be in the center of the page.It sticks to the right side of the page.It didn't fit correctly.PLS help

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{0.4cm} | m{2cm}| m{3.3cm} | m{2cm} | m{3.3cm} |  m{0.9cm} |  m{1.9cm} |  m{2cm} | m{0.2cm} | }
  \hline
  $$\#$$  & $$\upsilon_1 (V)$$ & $$i_1(A)$$ & $$\upsilon_2 (V)$$ & $$i_2(A)$$ & $$V_s(V.)$$ & $$I(mA)$$ & $$i_1 + i_2(mA) $$ \\ 
  \hline
  $$1$$ & $$1.00\pm 8 \times10^{-3}$$ & $$1 \times10^{-3}\pm1\times10^{-5}$$ & $$1.04\pm8\times10^{-3}$$ & $$1.04\times10^{-4}\pm1.2\times10^{-6}$$ & $$1$$ & $$0.9\pm1.\times10^{-2}$$ & $$1.10$$ \\
  \hline
  $$2$$ & $$1.98\pm2\times10^{-2}$$ & $$1.98\times10^{-3}\pm2.4\times10^{-5}$$ & $$2.05\pm2\times10^{-2}$$ & $$2.05\times10^{-4}\pm2.5\times10^{-6}$$ & $$2$$ & $$2.0\pm2\times10^{-2}$$ & $$2.19$$ \\ 
  \hline
  $$3$$ & $$2.99\pm2\times10^{-2}$$ & $$2.99\times10^{-3}\pm3.6\times10^{-5}$$ & $$3.09\pm2\times10^{-2}$$ & $$3.09\times10^{-4}\pm3.7\times10^{-6}$$ & $$3$$ & $$3.1\pm4\times10^{-2}$$ & $$3.30$$ \\
  \hline
  $$4$$ & $$3.96\pm3\times10^{-2}$$ & $$3.96\times10^{-3}\pm4.8\times10^{-5}$$ & $$4.09\pm3\times10^{-2}$$ & $$4.09\times10^{-4}\pm4.9\times10^{-5}$$ & $$4$$ & $$4.3\pm5\times10^{-2}$$ & $$4.37$$ \\
  \hline
  $$5$$ & $$4.97\pm4\times10^{-2}$$ & $$4.97\times10^{-3}\pm6.0\times10^{-5}$$ & $$5.11\pm4\times10^{-2}$$ & $$5.11\times10^{-4}\pm6.1\times10^{-5}$$ & $$5$$ & $$5.4\pm6\times10^{-2}$$ & $$5.48$$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Current and voltage values for different supply voltages in a parallel circuit.}
\label{table 1}

\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to redesign it, for example I would divide through your columns to remove the common exponent factors.

Comment: Why is everything typeset in dispaly math here? Note that the `$$...$$` should not be used with latex, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you switch to landscape mode, as otherwise you would need to impose an extremely small font size. (I'm not...) I'd further get rid of all 98 [!] instances of `$$`, mainly by switching to an `array` environment. Next, I'd use the `\unit` macro of the `siunitx` packages to denote scientific units such as Volt, Ampere, and milli-Ampere. I'd also provide some more visual (as well as logical) structure to the header material by placing the names of the variables and their associated units of measurement (Volt, Ampere, milli-Ampere, resp.) on separate lines.

Separately, I'm somewhat dubious about using `\upsilon` as the symbol to denote voltage variables; I'd rather use `v`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{siunitx}.   % for '\unit' macro
\usepackage{rotating}.  % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\newcommand\tz{{\times}}% no whitespace around the '\times' symbol

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2} % to replicate appearance of OP's screeshot
\[ % enter math mode
\begin{array}{ | *{8}{c|} }
  \hline
  \# & v_1 & i_1 & v_2 & i_2 & V_s & I & i_1 + i_2   \\[-12pt]
  & (\unit{\volt}) & (\unit{\ampere}) & (\unit{\volt}) & (\unit{\ampere}) & (\unit{\volt}) & (\unit{\milli\ampere}) & (\unit{\milli\ampere}) \\
  \hline
  1 & 1.00\pm 8 \tz10^{-3} & 1.00 \tz10^{-3}\pm1.0\tz10^{-5} & 1.04\pm8\tz10^{-3} & 1.04\tz10^{-4}\pm1.2\tz10^{-6} & 1 & 0.9\pm1\tz10^{-2} & 1.10 \\
  \hline
  2 & 1.98\pm2\tz10^{-2} & 1.98\tz10^{-3}\pm2.4\tz10^{-5} & 2.05\pm2\tz10^{-2} & 2.05\tz10^{-4}\pm2.5\tz10^{-6} & 2 & 2.0\pm2\tz10^{-2} & 2.19 \\
  \hline
  3 & 2.99\pm2\tz10^{-2} & 2.99\tz10^{-3}\pm3.6\tz10^{-5} & 3.09\pm2\tz10^{-2} & 3.09\tz10^{-4}\pm3.7\tz10^{-6} & 3 & 3.1\pm4\tz10^{-2} & 3.30 \\
  \hline
  4 & 3.96\pm3\tz10^{-2} & 3.96\tz10^{-3}\pm4.8\tz10^{-5} & 4.09\pm3\tz10^{-2} & 4.09\tz10^{-4}\pm4.9\tz10^{-5} & 4 & 4.3\pm5\tz10^{-2} & 4.37 \\
  \hline
  5 & 4.97\pm4\tz10^{-2} & 4.97\tz10^{-3}\pm6.0\tz10^{-5} & 5.11\pm4\tz10^{-2} & 5.11\tz10^{-4}\pm6.1\tz10^{-5} & 5 & 5.4\pm6\tz10^{-2} & 5.48 \\
  \hline
\end{array}
\]
\caption{Current and voltage values for different supply voltages in a parallel circuit.}
\label{table 1}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much! really appreciate it. @Mico